# which programming language does Facebook use for its different parts

Tags: facebook, programming-languages

I am wondering what programming language (Php, Ajax, ...) facebook uses. What kind of database server? for "view older posts"? what considerations for high traffic and security? Can anybody help me? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: AJAX is not a programming language.

Comment: This is not the place to discuss this question.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot remove it. Could you do this for me?

Answer (score 1):

PHP. http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358

Answer (score 1):

Facebook use MYSQL for its DBMS. the node of MYSQL over than 2000 node. "for older posts" it maybe also use this DBMS and use AJAX for increase its efficiency for loading from database.

Comment: They also use Casandra and compiled PHP

Answer (score 1):

One way to find out what a site/company uses is to look at their open positions, facebook has several listed here: http://www.facebook.com/careers/department.php?dept=engineering